# SVN command to show the Last Commit Author

Tags: svn, jenkins-pipeline

So I am working with a very old svn running on an old jenkins server. I am trying to output/print the last commit author using svn command.
So far I have tried -  `svn info --show-item last-changed-author`
But this doesn't work as my svn is too old and it gives following error-

```
+ svn info --show-item last-changed-author
svn: invalid option: --show-item
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

Could anyone please suggest me any other way to print/output the last commit author.

Comment: Can you include the output of plain `svn info` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `svn info` shows

```
Last Changed Author: user
```

You can use `sed` to extract the information:

```
svn info | sed -n '/^Last Changed Author:/s/^[^:]*: //p'
```

Some versions of sed might need a more verbose variant, e.g.

```
sed -n -e '/^Last Changed Author:/s/^[^:]*: //' -eta -eb -e:a -ep
```